# Unable to run For Each Controller in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have list of names in my application which I extracted using regular expression extractor. Now i need to add `ForEach Controller` to run through the list of names but I am unable to get it working. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?
[image]
[image]

[image: Regular Expression Extractor]
[image: ForEach Controller]

Comment: Could you please post the details of Regular Expression Extractor and the ForEach controller? A screenshot of them should help identify the issue here.

Comment: I have attached screen shots

Comment: Can you please describe the problem? From the log you posted it seems the regex is matching against strings at least 12 times. The other screenshots shot a correctly configured regex extractor, and a correct ForEach controller configuration. If you look in the View Results Tree listener, do you see requests to "rest/items/[...]"?

Comment: yes ,but in the Request "POST https://devtest.fueblabs.com/rest/items/35_fueb11_Switch_L8%20"                                                                                       Responses is {"error":{"message":"HTTP 404 Not Found","http-code":404,"exception":{"class":"javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException","message":"HTTP 404 Not Found","localized-message":"HTTP 404 Not Found"}}}

Comment: if i use the in the path like "rest/items/${name_1}" this its working in case i user path "rest/items/${name_index}"  displaying as 404 not found exception

Comment: So to review the problem; making a request to POST [...]/rest/items/${name_1} will resolve to a different URL than the first request in the loop using POST [...]/rest/items/${name_index}? Using the configuration you've set up it should be resolving to the same request: devtest.fueblabs.com/rest/items/35_fueb11_Switch_L8%20. The only thing I can see that might be a problem is that there is a space on the end (encoded into %20). Can you double check the URL generated by making a request using ${name_1} and the first ${name_index} request in the ForEach loop? Please post both these URLs.

Comment: Okay, First :  rest/items/${name_index} its displaying POST https://devtest.fueblabs.com/rest/items/35_fueb11_Switch_L8%20,                               Second: rest/items/${name_1} its displaying POST https://devtest.fueblabs.com/rest/items/35_fueb11_Switch_L8                                      how to remove that spaces please let me know

Comment: Its resolve now , but unable to run For Each Controller its only running one time instead of number of iteration for the list which we have in our application.as i already attached screen in the above .

Comment: I resolved thanks for the response.